# Counting missing values in a Pandas loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

- How can I run a loop in Pandas that returns a list that contains missing     values as zeros?

The loop should take the values in the
   full_scores_list, check whether that value is in the Home_team_scores
   column. If so calculate and output the frequency, otherwise return
   zero.

I have a long list that has different scores for a team for two league seasons.

```
       My code is:
       all_scores = []
       for score in range(0,len(full_scores_list)):
           if full_scores_list[score] == '0 0':
                    all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['0 0'])
           elif full_scores_list[score] == '0 1':
                   all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['0     1'])
           elif full_scores_list[score] == '0 2':
                all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['0 2']) 
               all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['0 2'])
           elif full_scores_list[score] == '0 3':
               all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['0 3'])
           elif full_scores_list[score] == '0 4':
               all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['0 4'])
           elif full_scores_list[score] == '0 5':
               all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['0 5'])  
           if full_scores_list[score] == '1 0':
                all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['1 0'])
           elif full_scores_list[score] == '1 1':
               all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['1 1'])
           elif full_scores_list[score] == '1 2':
               all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['1 2'])
           elif full_scores_list[score] == '1 3':
               all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['1 3'])
           elif full_scores_list[score] == '1 4':
               all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['1 4'])
           elif full_scores_list[score] == '1 5':
               all_scores.append(data1.Home_team_scores.value_counts()['1 5'])


       all_scores
```

Comment: Below is my code which does not work:

Comment: The following is my code, which does not work:

Comment: At least you tried

Comment: I want to extract and append in a list all scores for a team from '0 0', '0 1'... all the way to '5 5'. Where a score is missing, I want the code to return 0. How can I do this? I am getting the following error:

Comment: full_scores_list = ['0 0', '0 1', '0 2', '0 3', '0 4', '0 5',
                    '1 0', '1 1', '1 2', '1 3', '1 4', '1 5',
                    '2 0', '2 1', '2 2', '2 3', '2 4', '2 5',
                    '3 0', '3 1', '3 2', '3 3', '3 4', '3 5',
                    '4 0', '4 1', '4 2', '4 3', '4 4', '4 5',
                    '5 0', '5 1', '5 2', '5 3', '5 4', '5 5']

Comment: Don't put additional information in comments. Instead, edit your question.

Answer (score -1):

How about something along the lines:

```
com_vals = df['Home_team_scores'].unique()
df['full_scores_list'].apply(lambda v: v in com_vals)
```

Improved according to comments:

Instead of the lambda-function, you can use a helper function for the `apply()`:

```
com_vals = df['Home_team_scores'].unique()
def helper():
  return v in com_vals
df['full_scores_list'].apply(helper)
```

You can have more fine-grained control on the outputs and conditions with the `helper()` function.

Comment: Thanks. I have used the solution you have suggested, but I am still getting an error:

Comment: com_vals = data1['Home_team_scores'].unique()
data1['full_scores_list'].apply(lamda v: v in com_vals)

Comment: File "<ipython-input-45-6c512429cd24>", line 2
    data1['full_scores_list'].apply(lamda v: v in com_vals)
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax    My df id data1

Comment: I want the final array to include all possible scores, returning zero if that score is not in home team scores, otherwise return the sum of the score. How can I go about it? Im my list there are 36 possible scores

Comment: I have tried this, but I get the error: Key error: 'full_scores_list'                                               full_scores_list = ['0 0', '0 1', '0 2', '0 3', '0 4', '0 5',
                    '1 0', '1 1', '1 2', '1 3', '1 4', '1 5',
                    '2 0', '2 1', '2 2', '2 3', '2 4', '2 5',
                    '3 0', '3 1', '3 2', '3 3', '3 4', '3 5',
                    '4 0', '4 1', '4 2', '4 3', '4 4', '4 5',
                    '5 0', '5 1', '5 2', '5 3', '5 4', '5 5']
com_vals = data1['Home_team_scores'].unique()
data1['full_scores_list'].apply(lambda v: v in com_vals)

Comment: @MarcelZoll, you misspelled the `lambda` keyword. I've edited it.

Comment: Thank you all of you for your input. I will try it out and get back. I have appreciated your effort.

Comment: FWIW, there's a more efficient way than `lambda v: v in com_vals` or that `helper` function: use the `com_vals.__contains__` method as the arg to `.apply`.

Comment: @PM_2Ring okay, after a quick search I found `pandas.Series.isin()` which could have been indeed used as a substitute; but I highly disadvise to use the internal binding functions coming with double underscores and rather opt for the external functions/operations they bind to (which the most often always do)